# Returning plain String in Rest service does not return json?

Tags: java, rest

I created the following rest methods in my rest based web service

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("plain")
public String getPlain()
{
    return "hello world";
}

@GET
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("wrapper")
public Response getWrapper()
{
    return Response.ok(new Object(){ public String data = "hello world";}).build();
}
```

When I call plain service, it returns a raw string **hello world** rather than a JSON formatted output. However, wrapping the string in an object returns the JSON **{"data":"hello world"}**

Why is it showing such a behaviour? How do I send the plain String as JSON?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gipxf/index.html

Comment: Did you tried to remove the @Produces annotation?

Comment: Why would i remove @Produces annotation when all i want is a json? Whatever, i gave it a try...doesn't help.

Comment: What makes you think that "hello world" is not valid JSON?

Comment: @albogdano `"hello world"` is valid json but `hello world` is not. He said that the endpoint returns the latter

Answer (score 1):

I think these will give you what you need.

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("plain")
public String getPlain()
{
return JSONObject.quote("Hello World");
}
```

OR

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("plain")
public String getPlain()
{
return "\"Hello World\"";
}
```

OR

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("plain")
public char[] getPlain()
{
return "Hello World!".toCharArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above option, it does not work.

```
String result="hello world";
return result;
```

The reason why String is not getting auto-converted seems to be due to missing @XmlRootElement.  Based on the docuementation in cxf http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-data-bindings.html#JAX-RSDataBindings-HandlingJAXBbeanswithoutXmlRootElementannotations we need to use some jaxbElementClassMap. But unable to find further details.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
@GET 
@Produces("application/json") 
@Path("plain") 
public String getPlain() 
{ 
String result= "hello world";
    return result;
}
```

JSON needs a key-value pair.

Comment: JSON needs a key-value pair OR an array

Comment: @DavidGrant yeah, key-value pair in above question context.

Comment: @DavidGrant: A JSON value can be any JSON value. Whether an implementation supports root-values other than object (or array) is another thing.

Comment: ... also, in your example there is no key-value pair. There's only a string